# Blocking async queues Java

Tags: java, concurrency, queue, java-threads

I'm trying to figure out a way to implement the following in Java.

Thread1 will add jobs to queue1.
Another different thread (Thread2) will add jobs to queue2.

In the run() method of Thread1 I wait until there's a job in queue 1, and let's say I will print it, if and only if there are no awaiting jobs in queue2.

How may I notify Thread1 that Thread2 has added a job in queue2? 
Here is Thread1 Class

```
public class Thread1 implements Runnable {
private List queue1 = new LinkedList();

public void processData(byte [] data, int count) {
    byte[] dataCopy = new byte[count];
    System.arraycopy(data, 0, dataCopy, 0, count);
    synchronized(queue1) {
        queue1.add(data);
        queue1.notify();
    }
}

public void run() {
    byte [] data;

    while(true) {
        // Wait for data to become available
        synchronized(queue1) {
            while(queue1.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    queue1.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
            data = (byte[]) queue1.remove(0);
        }
        // print data only if queue2 has no awaiting jobs in it
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is the producer waiting for jobs in queue1 if it's supposed to be adding them to it?

Comment: yes sorry, the producer name was misleading

Comment: No, misleading is when you say: "Thread1 will add jobs to queue1" and "In the run() method of Thread1 I wait until there's a job in queue 1".

Comment: Ok i Will explain better with a code example

Comment: In your code example it looks like your `Thread1` is the consumer.

Comment: In fact both are consumers, I just need a way to handle the print condition

Comment: I wonder what would be a good method to check if a queue `isEmpty`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not quite well explained your question and I am not sure what you are trying to ask -its very confusing to read what you have written. Also, I don't see any code for `Thread-2` and `Queue-2`.

So I am going to put general advice,

1.**Use existing implementation of Blocking Queue** instead of doing `private List queue1 = new LinkedList();` and then doing `synchronized(queue1)`.

Here is [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) of `BlockingQueue` interface. You can use class , `LinkedBlockingQueue` as implementation.

2.**Sample code** - If you browse above link of `BlockingQueue` documentation, you see code at the bottom highlighting as how to write consumers and producers. There you don't see instance of queue getting created inside Thread class but set via constructor - that way you can share a single queue with as many threads as you like - by passing reference to queue in `Runnable` constructor.

3.**BlockingQueue implementations are thread-safe**  - so you don't have to `synchronize`on queue instances. You can freely pass queue instances to as many threads as you like believing that its methods will be called in synchronized way.

So I suggest that you try to rewrite whatever program you are trying to write using above construct and code samples and come back for any more questions.

Hope it helps !!